# How many back links should be created within 7 days?

Tags: seo, backlinks, link-building

I am trying to understand the best link building process. I am confused that my ranking dropped when I worked daily on one website.

Comment: There are many opinions about how aggressively you should build links; or even if you should build links at all.   While this question seems to call for opinions, there is lots of experience that could be shared answering this question as well as links articles that back up opinions and official advice from search engines.

Comment: Maybe so but the question shows no research, is incredibly thin and is borderline spam - it will only attract a stupid amount of equally spammy answers all bleating on about high PR and dofollow links. It will soon destroy the purpose of leaving this open as will be awash with poor and useless advice like the answer below.